# Android TextView задать текст в начале и в конце

Tags: android, android-textview

Необходимо задать текст внутри `TextView`, в начале *вьюхи* и в конце, пример:

```
.......................................
.StartText                     endText.
.......................................
```

Еще при этом иметь возможность перед `StartText` вставить картинку.

Находил [статью](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12671980), в которой было частичное решение, но оно у меня не работает, и, полагаю, что уже ни у кого не работает.

Одно из видимых мною решений: получить `getWeight TextView` (в пикселях), привести их в *dp*, получить `textSize`, умножить его на количество символов (`StartTextendText`) — 16 в данном случае, отнять их в приведенном размере от ширины и оставшееся место заполнить пробелами, после просто вставить кастомную строку в `TextView`.

Но как по мне, это слишком сложный «велосипед», и можно как-то легче.

Comment: а что сгруппировать картинку и два `TextView` в горизонтальный `LinearLayout` разместив виджеты нужным образом - не вариант, зачем такие сложности ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предлогаю два решение.
1.Создать контейнер LinearLayout\RelativeLayout и поместить внутри него два textView.
2.Создать Custom View.Внутри него поместить два TextView.

p.s. Если продемонстрировайте часть исходника кода, то получите больше ответов.